# FFMPEG - loop image over concatenated audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bunch of audio inputs that I concatenate to get the final audio. I would like to loop an image over this audio. Without -loop it works on my machine but wont upload to vimeo or youtube. Using -loop the encoding never stops. Using -shortest does not work. I believe this is because the final audio is not an input stream. How can I go about this?

This is the command i'm using, with some inputs supressed as to try and make it less spammy:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i "D:/Programas/FFMPEG/background.jpg" -i "D:\Musical Chairs (feat. Stoneface, Prodigal Sunn & Hell Razah).flac" -i "Medina 718.flac" (...inputs...) -i "D:\Legacy.flac" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=600:-1[ovrl]; [0:V]drawtext=fontsize=25:fontfile="D:/Programas/FFMPEG/font.ttf":fontcolor=white:text=Royal Fam:x=W/2+W/10.5:y=H/11[f1], [f1]drawtext=fontsize=25:fontfile="D:/Programas/FFMPEG/font.ttf":fontcolor=white:text=Yesterday Today Iz Tomorrow:x=W/2+W/10.5:y=2*(H/10)[f2],[f2]drawtext=fontsize=25:fontfile="D:/Programas/FFMPEG/font.ttf":fontcolor=white:text=2000:x=W/2+W/10.5:y=3*(H/10)[bg]; [bg][ovrl]overlay=(W-w)/7:(H-h)/2; [1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a][7:a][8:a][9:a][10:a][11:a][12:a]concat=n=12:v=0:a=1[final]" -map 0:v -map [final]:a -shortest -r 1 -movflags +faststart "RoyalFamYesterday.mp4"
```

TL;DR of the above command: Loop single frame; concatenate a lot of audio tracks; single frame never stops looping even with -shortest in the output.

I have since found a hacky solution: calculate the length of all songs in my python script and pass it over to the loop using -t. I would however like to know if there's a native way to do this within ffmpeg.

Comment: Share full command and log.

Comment: I've edited my question with the command.